# Microsoft Graph - Unable to access user profile data after Limiting calendar access

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on an application that I set up with application permission to User.Read.All and Calendar.ReadWrite.

I then limited the calendar access to an email security group as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#supported-permissions-and-additional-resources).
It appears that this is also limiting access to user profiles although the documentation doesn't indicate it that it should.

When attempting to get a users profile photo like:

```
Client.Users[email].Photos["240x240"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

it errors with message:

```
  Message: Access to OData is disabled.
  Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: a383deee-c7df-4812-969a-1b06235bfcd1
    date: 2020-03-11T19:29:39
  ClientRequestId: a383deee-c7df-4812-969a-1b06235bfcd1
```

Is this expected? How would I go about opening up User.Read.All to all users while limiting Calendar.ReadWrite to the email security group?

Comment: What is the value of the 'email' variable? Is it the users email address or the security group?

Comment: It is a users email who is not in the security group given access.

Comment: From the information you have provided, I do not see a surface issue. When requesting for the photo, can you send the request without Calendar.ReadWrite?

Comment: Try making the same request, without the SDK, on Graph Explorer, while logged in and see what happens. Use the preview (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) which has a permissions tab.

Comment: I am using a confidential client application, I don't see any way to connect to Graph Explorer in that way.  I guess what I am trying to ask is: Does an ApplicationAccessPolicy restrict access to all application permissions?